# SWT for tray icon in Swing application

Tags: java, swt, system-tray, trayicon

The tray icon implementation in Java 1.6 has its limitations, e.g. no support for the alpha channel in the graphic icons. Did anybody tried to use SWT to support a native looking tray icon? Is that possible at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I gave it a try: it works fine on Windows but on Linux it crashes as soon as I close a `JFrame` or `JDialog`. It looks like SWT gets confused by the AWT windows on its Linux implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I would think that you'd just use native calls - I doubt that SWT would be doing much for you at that point.